# how to go about executing this GET request to get the Temporary token for Redgifs

Tags: android, api

Please help me to get temporary token for API access from Redgifs. below is the instrution from their wiki. i do not know how to make the GET request. when i tried to send a get request to "https://api.redgifs.com/v2/auth/temporary HTTP/1.1". i get 404 error. Am i missing any header information. please advise

The details from wiki:

- GET /v2/auth/temporary HTTP/1.1
- Host: api.redgifs.com

Accept: application/json

```
{
   "token":"...",
   "addr":"2a00::579f:3c01:b94e",
   "agent":"curl/7.81.0",
   "rtfm":"https://github.com/Redgifs/api/wiki/API-access"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the HTTP/1.1 from your request and it will work